# Unable to install derbyjs: "No compatible version found"

Tags: node.js, npm, derbyjs

I'm trying to install derbyjs on ubuntu.
I do:

```
sudo npm install -g derby
```

But I get this:

```
<200 response code here>
npm ERR! error installing uglify-js@2.4.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/browser-resolve/-/browser-resolve-0.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! error installing racer@0.5.4
<200 response code here>
npm ERR! error installing derby@0.5.4
<200 response code here>

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: source-map@'>=0.1.7- <0.2.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.0","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/imkost/node/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "derby"
npm ERR! cwd /home/imkost/node
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: source-map@'>=0.1.7- <0.2.0-'
npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
npm ERR! message ["0.0.0","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3"]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/imkost/node/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. Any ideas?

`nodejs version: 0.10.22`

`npm version: 1.3.15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me, where do you get derby dependency on `source-map`?

Here's dependencies for derby taken from `npm info derby`

```
dependencies: 
 { 'dom-shim': '~0.1.1',
   'html-util': '~0.1.5',
   tracks: '~0.3.2',
   racer: '0.5.12',
   chokidar: '~0.6.2',
   stylus: '~0.32.1',
   less: '~1.3.3',
   nib: '~0.9.1',
   commander: '~1.1.1',
   mkdirp: '~0.3.5',
   MD5: '~1.0.1',
   async: '~0.2.8' },
devDependencies: 
 { 'coffee-script': '*',
   'expect.js': '*',
   mocha: '*',
   sinon: '*' },
```

BTW, I'm using `node v0.10.21` and `npm v1.3.11`.

Try doing a local install: `npm install derby`. Does this fail too?

If `derby` installs fine, you have issues installing other modules, try to isolate root cause of the problem, and then let us know if you're unable to get going.

Comment: Strange thing. I've just tried what you've said: `npm install derby`. No errors. Then tried `npm install -g derby`. No errors. So, the problem was solved by **not using sudo**. Why? I don't know. Thanks for help!

Comment: Prefer not to use `sudo` for npm installs, even for global modules, set npm to use `/usr/local/npm` or something. `chmod the `/usr/local` to your user account, so that you don't have to use `sudo`. I don't think not using `sudo` made it work, but could be due to lock files, can't say for sure.